# How to change the Pin used for the 1-wire Bus

Tags: gpio, 1-wire

By default the header Pin Nr. 7 us used by the 1-wire kernel module.

I would like to change it to a one of the 4 new GPIO Pins of an Rev 2 Pi.

Comment: The kernel code for bitbanging 1wire on the RPi is a bit messy at the moment, multiple implementations exist. But unless I missed something completely, the only way to change this pin at this moment is to recompile the module, a name that keeps popping up in this context is 'Frank Buss', see for example this thread on the [RPi forum](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=6649&start=75)

Comment: For the Raspberry Pi Model 3B+, and presumably everything else running the current OS, the default pin is now pin 4.

Comment: @Bob Brown I think the default was always GPIO 4 (which is header pin 7).

Answer (score 9):

To change the default GPIO pin used for 1-wire communication you can edit the `/boot/config.txt` file and add this line:

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=x
```

where `x` is the GPIO pin you want to use. Reboot to see the change.

Comment: Great answer. There is so much misinformation about this question out there. Simple, worked with Raspi 2+ and Raspi 3 with current Raspian.

Comment: Yea it took me a while to find this out myself, the incorrect answers out there is what prompted me to answer this question to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

## Important remark

it must be exactly as indicated, **without any space between parameters and values in the command**

As written above in `/boot/config.txt`

```
 dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=x
```