# Picademy Parts Kit Immersible Temperature Probe Pinout

Tags: ds18b20

I have a Picademy parts kit (12 of them, actually) from Newark/Element 14.  These kits have an immersible temperature probe that I conjecture is based on a DS18B20.  However, there's no documentation.  The leads are brown, yellow, and blue.  If it's really a DS18B20, then the three leads are V+, data, and GND, but I can't tell which is which.

Does anyone know what this is, and which lead is which?  Thanks!

Edit: I did send a request to Newark's tech support.  They replied promptly, saying they had sent my inquiry on to the supplier.  2018-08-22: I got a reply from Newark confirming that the probe contains a DS18B20, but still no info on lead colors.

Another edit: After getting the answer from both Newark and my colleague, I've written this stuff up with more detail than I can easily put here.  **Beware: this applies only to the Picademy parts kit** temperature probe.
http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/faculty/rbrow211/raspberrypi/temp_probe/  (The link is probably good until I'm dead, after which it will be OK to comlpain about me.)

Comment: yellow - data, blue - gnd, brown -  vcc

Comment: @JaromandaX Why not make that the answer?

Comment: Because I'm only 99.9% sure

Comment: @JaromandaX So the answer could be "I'm pretty sure that yellow - data, blue - gnd, brown - vcc"

Comment: @JaromandaX  Very good guess.  However, when one does that, the probe gets hot enough to burn fingers and the GPIO pin one used no longer works.  Don't feel bad, though.  I made that guess before asking here.  There are five more possibilities.

Comment: Lol. You are using 3v3 not 5v right?

Comment: @JaromandaX  Yes, 3v3 connected to the brown lead.  There was no actual smoke, so the probe *may* still be good. {sigh}

Comment: I've powered DS18B20 the wrong way around.  They do get very hot.  Mine still worked when I swapped the power leads.

Comment: No Datasheet? No sale!

Comment: @joan My DS18B20 still works.  Too pad GPIO 4 is smoked, though. {rueful grin}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten answers from two places, they agree, and I've tested them!  A colleague in another state and Newark's tech support both say:
Brn: GND
Blu: V+ (use 3v3)
Yel: Data

I've tried this and it works, as long as you haven't smoked pin 4.  If you *have* smoked pin 4, or otherwise need to change the 1-Wire pin,see [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4844/how-to-change-the-pin-used-for-the-1-wire-bus#comment140836_4844).

Answer (score 0):

had this same question today - so yellow is clearly "data", but I'm confused on thread's reference to vcc / gnd.  Adafruit's website says:

If your sensor has three wires - Red connects to 3-5V, Blue/Black connects to ground and Yellow/White is data

... mine has the same yellow / blue / brown combo as mentioned here.  Are you concluding that brown - vcc, blue - gnd is wrong (i.e. gets hot)

Comment: Yes, that's wrong.  It will burn your fingers and smoke whatever GPIO pin you connected yellow to.  I'm not even sure we can conclude that yellow is data.

Comment: And also... I probably should have written V+ instead of Vcc.  I've edited the question.